# Color value is highlighted

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, colors

how to get rid of the color that wraps the value in vscode? I want to be there only the little square in the left side

[.nav-link-wrapper a {
color: #ec0b0b
}
]

[image]

Comment: Can you rephrase that? It is unclear what you want to achieve. To get rid of a color property, just remove the entire line from the CSS.

Comment: Around #ec0b0b is the red colour. I want to eliminate that red color that wraps #ec0b0b but the red square to  be still there. I hope you understand. Thanks :)

Comment: i made it by uninstalling the pigments package 

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your settings:

```
"css.colorDecorators.enable": false
```

Related thread:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10943#issuecomment-291572843